Trying to make a Pip-Boy like game with LED buttons on a breadboard
I'm new to making electronics and I'm having a hard time of going about this. I have had a little help but I'm stuck.
The way I'm wanting to have the circuit work is there are 3 LEDs with 3 switches connected ( with the LEDs very close t its switch so it can behave like the real Pip-Boy). So each LED has its own momentary push button switch.
What I'm trying to accomplish is when I hit the momentary button it will light up its LED and stay on until I press button number 2 which will shut off the first LED without hitting its button and so on with the third, so no matter which button I press it will kill power to the previously pressed button's LED.
I'm not the best with translating circuit diagrams to the breadboard but I'm willing to try anything without an Arduino or Raspberry Pi, I wasn't wanting to code anything due to the Pip-Boy being a limited size. Thank you

This is the ideal use case for an Arduino.

An Arduino micro or mini is going to be smaller than anything you can put together on a breadboard, but if you don't want to do any programming I have the feeling you could do something with a transparent D-type latch.

You don’t need no stinkin’ Arduino.
What you need is a latch for each button A, B, C.
When A is pressed you want to Set the A latch on.
But if either B or C is pressed you want to Reset the A latch to off.

The set/reset latch is easily accomplished with two NOR gates.
The OR function is easily accomplished with two more NOR gates.

You get 4 NOR gates in the cheapest 14-pin DIP package you can buy (CD4001, 74HC02, etc).
So the whole thing can be done with three quad NOR ICs and a few resistors and your switches and LEDs.

I chose to use the inverted Q output to drive the LEDs because some gates are better at sinking current than sourcing.
EDIT to show NAND version
With NAND gates the Set and Reset inputs become active low, so the inputs now idle high and are pulled low with the switch.
We still want an OR function but that’s ok because you can convert an AND to/from an OR by inverting all the inputs and outputs (DeMorgan’s theorem). This works to our advantage because the NAND converts to an OR with active low inputs, which is what we have. The 4th gate is just an inverter to create an active low signal: creates an active low Reset when either input goes low.

So the final circuit would be something like:

EDIT#2 to show 74LS00 pinout
Here is what one section should look like.

The other two sections are copies so work on getting a single section working first. Make sure pressing the A button turns the light on and that it stays on when you release the button. Verify the LED turns off when the B button is pressed. Turn it back on with A and verify it turns off again when C button is pressed.
There's no guarantee which state the set/reset flip flop will power up in. If you want to guarantee the A LED turns on (and B and C turns off) at power up you could add a capacitor (.01 to 1uF) across the A switch. This would have the effect of pressing the button briefly on power up to get it into a known state.

You can implement the same scheme using three quad NAND gates by inverting the logic as necessary.

You guys are amazing, thank you both so much. I have several quad nand Gates when I was trying to use other people's projects to splice together my own, how would I invert the logic in order to do so?

I added the NAND version to the answer. Fun project, and thanks for enlightening me to the PipBoy universe.

For one,thank you so much for your time.I've tried to wrap my head around this but truly I'm unable to grasp what's right in front of me.Turns out that I have several three input nand and several 2 input nand gates not quadruple inputs.I'm struggling understanding how to convertthe 4inout nand to satisfy the diagram you've shown. It gets more confusing when I'm trying to then do this on a breadboard. Looking it up online hasn't helped when seeing it play out practically.I know i'm difficult, but is there any way you could help clarify it further for a stick thumper like me? if not it's okay.

You only need two-input NAND gates. If you have a three (or four) input NAND gate then just tie the extra input pin(s) high. One of the NAND gates in each section is just being used as an inverter so any inverter will work there, e.g. a hex inverter (HC04 or HC14) or a NOR (with all inputs tied together).

So I've wired and then rewired the circuit only to have both temps turn out to have two lights on and one off and the buttons don't do much other than turn the circuit off for a moment.I'm assuming I have an inverted from the positives to negatives from the switch to the end which is the led. In your diagram I interpreted the initial switch to have started from negative to a resistor then it goes to the circuit and ends on LED with it connecting to positive  but that doesn't yield anything, the board doesn't light up at all. Should I change the set side to the LED and resets the same?

What are the part numbers of the parts you are using, and what power supply voltage are you using?

For the nand gates I'm using sn74LS00n. 3 of them total because they are quad input, so each one for each LED. I'm using 5v on the circuit. I believe the module is a mb102 power module, 3v,5v,7v,12v. 330 ohm resistor from power to the LEDs, could have tried 1K resistor from the switch to negative and 10K from things I've tried to put in finding online. trying to get it to work.

I actually use my multimeter to test out how many volts my breadboard is pushing out. My power module is supposed to be able to have a volt selector more or less, 5 volt off or 3 volt but I am getting around 9 vollts or so. I have a feeling a lot of what's messing me up is the diagram to implementing it to a real circuit

I added an explicit schematic for the 74LS00. One last thing - make sure your switches are in fact "momentary contact". This circuit won't work if the switch is a latching type, i.e. toggles between on and off every time you press it.
